# XML Attributes parsing

Tags: android, xml, xmlpullparser

I'm building an application in which I have to parse `XML` attributes. My `XML` looks like this:

```
<ad type="interstitial" animation="none">
<interstitial preload="0" autoclose="0" type="url" url="http://account.mobfox.com/activation_vad.php" orientation="portrait">       
</interstitial>
</ad>
```

I have tried using the following code:

```
try {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);

    XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
    XmlPullParser parser1 = factory.newPullParser();
    parser1.setInput(new StringReader(xml));

    while (!"interstitial".equals(parser1.getName())
        && parser1.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        parser1.next();
    }

    Log.d("URL --> ", parser1.getAttributeValue(null, "url"));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But, I'm not able to print `URL` from the attributes.
What am I doing wrong? Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: exceptions or what is being outputted may help.

Comment: Got `exceptions` like this: `11-29 16:08:54.124: W/System.err(30206): java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-29 16:08:54.134: W/System.err(30206):  at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-29 16:08:54.134: W/System.err(30206):  at android.util.Log.d(Log.java:139)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
Log.d("URL --> ", ""+parser1.getAttributeValue(null, "url"));
```

beacuse maybe you are passing **parameter** in `Log.d` **empty** or **null**

**EDIT**

```
URL url = new URL("Your URL");
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                        .newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

                NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ad");

                for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                    Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                    Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
                    NodeList nameList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("interstitial");
                    Element nameElement = (Element) nameList.item(0);
                    nameList = nameElement.getChildNodes();                       

                    System.out.println("Value : "
                            + (nameElement.getAttribute("url")));
                }
```

Comment: Tried this getting `null` output.

Comment: @Anupam then you did't get the **URL**. url is null so that error. try my edit

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use xpath concept. It is easy to implement. Here is the [Link](http://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/12/24/android-xml-adventure-parsing-xml-using-xpath/)... Also you can run the query online [here](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi)...